# What are the best text-to-IPA converters that match the IPA transcriptions in the Oxford American English dictionary?

Tags: discussion, american-english, pronunciation, ipa

There are so many text to IPA converters available but I am having difficulty finding a text-to-IPA converter that consistently or closely matches the IPA transcriptions in the Oxford American English dictionary. As I am using this dictionary for developing my personal wirting system (using IPA), any discrepancies can negatively affect my vocabulary acquisition. Can you recommend a reliable tool for converting text to IPA transcriptions that align with this dictionary?

Oxford American English dictionary pronunciation guide and IPA symbols: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/about/pronunciation_american_english

Comment: Are you worried about things like *bird* being transcribed as bɜrd rather than bərd? Or are you worried about the IPA transcriber actually disagreeing with the Oxford American English Dictionary on the pronunciation of certain words?

Comment: The ideal converter should 100% matches Oxford American English dictionary. If it's not available, something like bɜrd can be accepted . But I worry more about "the IPA transcriber actually disagreeing with the Oxford American English Dictionary on the pronunciation of certain words". Because that can negatively impact my vocabulary acquisition

Comment: A dictionary that gives only one pronunciation for "American English" will never work. Most words have many, many, many different pronunciations in the real world.

Comment: I mean they should use the same database from Oxford American English

Comment: Oxford dictionaries don't make their database public, and [databases are protected by law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_right) in the UK (home of Oxford) and EU, so unauthorised use would be clearly prohibited; things are less rigorous under US law, but they may still have some legal claim. Oxford dictionaries don't seem to provide such a tool, so there are legal problems with developing your own, which explains why such a tool is at least hard to find. You could of course start with another database and convert it to Oxford format, but it would not match exactly.